# JavaScript: how to compute a reverse RegExp pattern for stripping characters that are matched by the source pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a pattern `/[a-z]+100/` (although it can be any pattern) and need to process the clipboard content to strip out characters that do not belong the `[a-z01]` range. Or be even more advanced, strip out everything that does not fit the `/[a-z]+100/` pattern itself. E.g: if clipboard has `12345abc200def500100`, then processed content will be stripped down to `abcdef100`.

Is it possible to automate this process, so that we could assume that any source pattern can be reversed?

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sence to me because that regex doesn't match anything in the given string (clipboard). But getting the "reverse" value should just be a matter of replacing the matching parts with noting i.e. `resultingString = clipboardString.replace(/anyRegEx/g, '');`.

Comment: Looks like too general to me. I think you should scale down the problem to a bit smaller and a bit specific denominator.d

Comment: @Ejay just noticed that it would not work anyway. Regex based transformation of the clipboard doesn't appear to be a sensible approach.

Comment: Did you mean to say `/[a-z]+|100/`?

Comment: The pattern declares the "valid" acceptable string, and it is true that it does not match anything in the given string as @ClasG pointed out. Suppose an input where any valid value must match the `/[a-z]+100/`. Now you paste `12345abc200def500100` and you don't wanna decline the entire paste data, just filter out everything that doesn't fit the `/[a-z]+100/`. That's the idea. I can decline the paste if input doesn't match, but I'd like to avoid that. So that user who pastes wouldn't get a feeling that something is broken.

Comment: Why should it be stripped down to `abcdef100`, and not simply -say- `f100`? What if there are multiple ways to produce a matching pattern from the subsetstrings, what if there is no way to match the pattern? In short, no, there is no "reverse regex", and no automated process to create one. Also a regex alone only *matches* things, it cannot process things like an algorithm would.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov: Well, if I do copy and paste `12345abc200def500100` but only `abcdef100` appears on the screen, *that* would give me the impression that something is broken (or worse, that I did something wrong). Better just tell the user that it's invalid. If you want, you can make autocorrection *suggestions* from which he might choose one to clean the data.

Answer (score 0):

As a general response to returning only the string matched by the regex you can write a simple global regex that returns anything matched and throws away anything else.  For example

```
var testString = '12345abc200def500100'
var testRegex = new RegExp(/[a-z01]/)

var returnString= testString.replace(new RegExp('((?:'+testRegex.source+')+)|.', 'g'), function(full, matched){
  return (typeof matched != "undefined") ? matched : '';
});
console.log(returnString)
```

When run in the console this logs '1abc00def00100'
You should be able to change out the variable testRegex with whatever regex you want to use.  For example using the regex [a-z][0-9] returns'c2f5'